# What is set exponentiation and what is its proof?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I recently learned about set exponentiation $B^{A}$, that is,

$B^{A} = \left \{ f \mid f:A\rightarrow B \right \}$

which is the set of all the functions which maps A to B. The number of function in a set exponentiation is given as $ \mid B \mid ^{\mid A \mid}$.

Let consider these sets S = {1,2,3} and T = {4,5}, then according to set exponentiation there are  $2^3=8$ functions which map the above sets S to T.

**Question 1:** Can you please provide a simple example function which maps the above sets S and T?  else can you provide another example for the same?

**Question 2:** How mathematicians proved the number of functions in set exponentiation is $ \mid B \mid ^{\mid A \mid}$ ?

Comment: Just map elements to elements..

Comment: As an aside, this is not explicitly "*exponentiation*"... The notation happens to resemble exponentiation and was likely chosen specifically for the convenience of having $|B^A|=|B|^{|A|}$, but it is built on more fundamental principles and different principles than the definitions used in arithmetic involving the number $e$.

Comment: For finite sets it's simply a matter of noting that for each of the $|A|$ elements of of $A$ you have $|B|$ choices of elements of $B$ then the each element of $A$ may be mapped to.  The eight functions of $S\to T$ are simply the $8$ choices that $1,2,3$ can be mapped to either $4$ or $5$.  That is: 1: $1\to 4;2\to 4;3\to4$, 2: $1\to 4; 2\to 4; 3\to 5;$ 3: $1\to 4; 2\to 5;3\to 4$; 4: $1\to 4; 2\to 5; 3\to 5;$  5: $1\to 5;2\to 4;3\to 4;$ 6: $1\to 5;2\to 4;3\to 5;$ 7:$1\to 5;2\to 5;3\to 4;$ 8: $1\to 5;2\to 5; 3\to 5$.... That's all.

Comment: Suppose the question were "How many ways can you make a three character string using the the two characters $4$ and $5$?".  The answer is for each position you have $2$ choices and you have three positions so you have three times you make the choice so the string is "$\{4,5\},\{4,5\},\{4,5\}$ and there are $2\cdot 2\cdot 2 = 2^3$ ways to do this.... Well, a string of three characters is nothing more or less than a *function* between string position $\to$ character value. In the domain you have three possible positions and in the range two possible characters. That's $2^3$ possible functions.

Comment: That is.... the eight functions are:  $123\to 444;  123\to 445; 123\to 454; 123\to 455; 123\to 544;123\to 545; 123\to 554; 123\to 555$.

Answer (score 1):

An example of a function $f:S \to T$ is given by
$$f(1) = 4, \ f(2) = 5, \ f(3) = 4.$$
To see why $\mathrm{card} \ T^S = (\mathrm{card} \ T)^{\mathrm{card} \ S}$, consider how we could define a function $g: S \to T$. We could set $g(1) = 4 \text{ or } 5$. Similarly, there are two options for the value $g(2)$ and two for the value of $g(3)$. Therefore, the number of different functions one could define is $$2\cdot2\cdot2 = 2^3 = (\mathrm{card} \ T)^{\mathrm{card} \ S}.$$

Edit: Of course, this logic can be extended to larger sets $S$ and $T$. The link provided in the comment has a good answer for that.